# How to make AKSequencer to stop automatically if it reached the end of the sequence?

Tags: ios, audiokit

I noticed that the AKSequencer continue playing (AKSequencer.isPlaying is true) even when there is no more notes to play in the sequence. Is it possible to make it auto-stop at the end of the sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` to trigger code based on the content that your sequencer is playing.  In this case, add an additional track and set it's output to `AKMIDICalllbackInstrument`.  Add an event to this track at the position that you want your sequencer to stop at (you can use `sequencer.length` if you don't know already know how long it is). Then set up the callback instrument's callback function to stop the sequencer when the event is received.

```
var seq = AKSequencer()
var callbackInst: AKMIDICallbackInstrument!
var controlTrack: AKMusicTrack!

func setUpCallback() {
    // set up a control track
    controlTrack = seq.newTrack()

    // add an event at the end
    // we don't care about anything here other than the position
    controlTrack.add(noteNumber: 60,
                     velocity: 60,
                     position: seq.length,
                     duration: AKDuration(beats: 1))

    // set up the MIDI callback instrument
    callbackInst = AKMIDICallbackInstrument()
    controlTrack?.setMIDIOutput(callbackInst.midiIn)

    // stop the sequencer when the control track's event's noteOn is recieved
    callbackInst.callback = { statusByte, _, _ in
        guard let status  = AKMIDIStatus(statusByte: statusByte) else { return }
        if status == .noteOn {
            self.seq.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the callback is never called. There is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682484/audiokit-4-6-release-akmidicallbackinstrument-not-calling-back. And it is said this issue is fixed in the v4.6.1. I updated my audiokit pod to the latest version, but it is still not working.

Comment: Fixed it. It was not working because I have not enabled the Background Audio mode for the app.